# How to search for multiple words of a specific pattern and separator?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to trim out multiple hex words from my string. I'm searching for exactly 3 words, separated by exactly 1 dash each time.

i.e. for this input:

`wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0-1605296913-49b045f-19794354.jar`

I'd like to get this output:

`wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0.jar`

I was able to remove the hex words by repeating the pattern. How can I simplify it? Also, I wasn't able to change * to +, to avoid allowing empty words. Any idea how to do that?

What I've got so far:

```bash
# Good, but how can I simplify?
% echo 'wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0-1605296913-49b045f-19794354.jar' | sed 's/\-[a-fA-F0-9]*\-[a-fA-F0-9]*\-[a-fA-F0-9]*//g'
druid-indexing-service-0.20.0.jar
# Bad, I'm allowing empty words
% echo 'wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0-1605296913-49b045f-.jar' | sed 's/\-[a-fA-F0-9]*\-[a-fA-F0-9]*\-[a-fA-F0-9]*//g'
druid-indexing-service-0.20.0.jar
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I had a typo in original output, thank you [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
s='wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0-1605296913-49b045f-19794354.jar'

sed -E 's/(-[a-fA-F0-9]{3,})+//' <<< "$s"

wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0.jar
```

**Breakup:**

- `(`: Start a group

  - `-`: Match a hyphen
  - `[a-fA-F0-9]{3,}`: Match 3 or more hex characters
- `)+`: End the group. Repeat this group 1+ times

Comment: This is assuming that `wonder-indexing-service` is never `w0nder-in3xing-s3rvice` ?

Comment: @Zak: I made an update. Besides there has to be a hyphen before hex string.

Comment: +1 on this answer.  -- Small note (I don't know if OP mis-typed) But OP has retained the dash *before* the `.jar`  -- `wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0-.jar`  ... Again, not sure if it was a typo .. But I am assuming you are corect.

Comment: That indeed turned out to be a typo after comment and edit from @yurmix

Comment: This worked, thanks! Only worked with -E (extended/modern regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `+` you have to escape it `\+`, but you can repeat matching 3 words prepended by a hyphen using a quantifier which also need escaping

```
\(-[a-fA-F0-9]\+\)\{3\}
```

Example

```
echo 'wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0-1605296913-49b045f-19794354.jar' | sed 's/\(-[a-fA-F0-9]\+\)\{3\}//g'
```

Output

```
wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0.jar
```

---

If you don't want to allow a trailing `-` then you can match the `.jar` and put that back in the replacement.

```
echo 'wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0-1605296913-49b045f-19794354.jar' | sed 's/\(-[a-fA-F0-9]\+\)\{3\}\(\.jar$\)/\2/g'
```

Comment: I ran your examples and they didn't work. My env is zsh on macOS. Thanks!

Comment: @yurmix Apparently on mac it seems different, but then with `-E` matching 3 words with a hyphen prepended `sed -E 's/(-[a-fA-F0-9]+){3}//g'`

Answer (score -1):

```
printf "wonder-indexing-service-0.20.0-1605296913-49b045f-19794354.jar" | cut -d'-' -f1-4 | sed s'@$@.jar@'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question(s) about (sed) patterns.